# Fill automatic data in second table when insert data in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table `Table1` and `Table2` and structure of table as

```
Table1          
Primary Key | Name      

Table2          
Primary Key |  Table1_Id_pk |  Status - true/false value
```

When I insert data into `Table2` I want to automatically transfer that data in `table1` from `Table2` which have `Status` false.

Comment: A trigger might be useful in this situation.

Comment: Trigger is bad , avoid it. and for this simple example, use @@identity..

Comment: what data you want to copy in table1 from table2 during insert? can you show examples?

Comment: @Ajay2707 - `@@IDENTITY` is not limited to current scope and can give you incorrect results. you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. refer [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: This is simple example, you can use here @@identity or scope_identity for transaction if you use. Bydefault sql manage this.. so no need to use scope_identity when you are not use transaction.

Comment: Using either `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` puts a limitation when working with data. You must `INSERT` one row only. In `SQL` you should work with batches, otherwise you are going to have performance issues. Processing one row at time is not a good practice at all.

Comment: @Anumpam, while insert into Table1 from Table2, what comes in name field.. Also why you want the reverse enginering.. means Table1 is master table table 2 is transaction (as reference given). So how we get Table1_Id_pk in first inset .. some thing wrong of your logic ... give sample and suggest what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `AFTER INSERT` [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DataMigration
ON Table2
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Table1
    SELECT *
    FROM TAble2
    WHERe Status = 'false'

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, use [@@identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) to get inserted row-id and use that id for child table.

```
declare @t1 table (pk int identity(1,1) not null , name varchar(50) )
declare @t2 table (pk int identity(1,1) not null , t1pk int, status bit )
declare @new_table1Id int

insert into @t1 values( 'ajay')

set @new_table1Id = @@IDENTITY -This gives you last inserted id of @t1
insert into @t2 values( @new_table1Id , 0)

select * from @t1
select * from @t2
```

[@@IDENTITY official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

Comment: As per OP, he wants to copy data from t2 to t1 when inserted in t2 with status = 'false' but in your case, you are copying identity from t1 to t2.

Comment: This solution should be avoid if possible because in most of the cases the data is inserted in batches. Processing a single row is harming the performances for sure. Also, if you are inserting the data from several stored procedures you need to edit all of them.

Comment: thanks guys, I not edit right now. because question is something wrong as need child table first and then insert into master table...  I am waiting still the updated question by @Anumpam